# Angular: how to handle the init/loading-problem best

Tags: angular

Lets say I read some data at the constructor of an Angular component out of a service (e.g. a service that handles REST for me).

```
export class MyComponent
{
  public data : any;

  constructor (private ws : MyWebService)
  {
    this.ws.getData ().subscribe  // e.g. HTTP-request
    (
      (resp) => 
      {
        this.data = resp;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The template would just show that data.

```
<div>{{ data }}</div>
```

Because data is not loaded before the component is renderd I would always get an undefined error in my javascript console for the very first loading.

To avoid the error I can check data before displaying.

```
  <div *ngIf="data!=undefined">{{ data }}</div>
```

Another way would be to init data and hope the fetch is quick.

Is there some better strategy to avoid this problem?

Comment: You could load the data in a route `resolve` which will prevent the page from loading until the data is ready https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a lot of strategies:

1. Doing `{{ data?.memberOfData }}` for safe member access.
2. Doing `<div *ngIf="data">{{ data }}</div>` for rendering a `div` only if data is not `undefined`
3. Placing a loading bar while the data loads. You can do that in an HttpInterceptor to make it application wide, or just in the component that you're working on.
4. Using the resolve guard which will prevent the loading of the component in `router-outlet` unless the data has loaded.
5. You could also use an `async` pipe:

   `this.data$ = this.ws.getData();`

then in template:

```
<div> {{ data$ | async | json }} </div>
```

I personally like the last(5th) one as we don't have to care about `unsubscribe`ing the `Subscription` in `ngOnDestroy` to avoid any memory leaks. It's a bit more cleaner.

It completely depends on your specific use case though. There isn't a good way or a bad way of doing it.